# Android Weird Huge Menu sizes

Tags: android, menu

Hi been trying to add a share feature to my app. Testing on Moto G.

But the ShareMenu is Huge and is even larger than the screen. Seems ok in portrait mode. But brakes in landscape.

http://postimg.org/image/ne7zzup43/

Anyway the original code  https://github.com/pocmo/Instant-Mustache/blob/article-09/src/com/androidzeitgeist/mustache/activity/PhotoActivity.java

seemed to work, maybe because its locked to portrait>

I had to change the code to add more menu items, the share sub menu went weird.

Heres my current code.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        uri = getIntent().getData();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo);

        ImageView photoView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo);
        photoView.setImageURI(uri);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_photo_menu, menu);
    //return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

         MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
         inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_photo_menu, menu);
         return true;
    }

    private void sharePhoto() {
        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        share.setType(MIME_TYPE);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_item_share:
            sharePhoto();
            return true;
        case R.id.take_another:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Go to main Activity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
        }

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    invalidateOptionsMenu(); ///????? Redraw Menu on rotate?????
}
```

Here is my current MENU XML

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
            android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            android:title="@string/action_share"/>

        <item android:title="@string/take_another" android:id="@+id/take_another"></item>

    </menu>
```

Manifest //(No SDK requirements set)

```
<activity android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.photo.PhotoActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"  />
```

PhotoActivity XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />
</LinearLayout>
```